# \normalfont in new theorem-like environment

Tags: fonts, formatting, theorems

How can I get universal in my new environment normalfont instead of italic (default)?
I thought it was something simple like

```
\newtheorem{exercise}{ \normalfont}[chapter] `
```

but doesn't work. I could not find something similar but I think it is something simple, even for me as a new user to LaTeX.

Comment: Usually by choosing a suitable `\theoremstyle`. But that depends a bit on the theorem related package(s) you use. If you add a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) to your question, it would be easier to find a solution.

Comment: this question is rather similar, though not identical, to [this one about spacing around theorems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37472/spacing-before-and-after-with-newtheoremstyle/37481#37481).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for I do not know the capabilities of `amsthm` but now thanks to you know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer the key--value syntax of the [thmtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package (which may use `amsthm` or `ntheorem` as backend).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont]{normalhead}
\declaretheorem[style=normalhead]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Some text.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @mbork: If you like my answer, upvote it. ;-)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to do that!  Fixed now;).

Comment: excellent package I just installed thanks @lockstep

Answer (score 11):

For instance (using `amsthm`) this.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello world}
\begin{example}
  I am an example of proper usage of the \texttt{amsthm} package.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

See also the documentation for `amsthm` for defining your own theorem styles, and also other theorem-generating packages (`ntheorem` being probably the most widely used).

Comment: Thanks @mbork this worked well. But if I have more than one `\newtheorem{example1}{Example1}[chapter]`and `\newtheorem{example2}{Example2}[chapter]` and I just want some of them are normal fonts and some defaultthen how can I do it?

Comment: divide your `\newtheorem` declarations by style, and put an appropriate `\theoremstyle` command before each group.  the current `\theoremstyle` stays in effect until overridden by a different one.

Comment: I just tried and indeed it works exactly as I like

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using `ntheorem`. Note that each declaration of

```
\newtheorem{...}
```

inherits the current `theoremstyle` and associated settings.

In the example below, both `mytheorem` and `anothertheorem` have *exactly* the same style. If you were to put some different settings, perhaps changing the `\theorembodyfont{}` for example, immediately before

```
\newtheorem{anothertheorem}{Another Theorem}
```

then `anothertheorem` would inherit these new settings. See the `ntheorem` documentation for more details.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}   % for theorems
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for sample text

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{}      % try commenting this line
\theoremprework{}       % code to process before the theorem 
\theorempostwork{}      % code to process after the theorem 
\theoremseparator{:}    % could be a : for example

% first theorem
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{My Theorem}

% another theorem
\newtheorem{anothertheorem}{Another Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{anothertheorem}
\lipsum[2] 
\end{anothertheorem}

\end{document}
```