# How to change the font shape in the body of theorem environments?

Tags: formatting, theorems, italic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
This is the first definition
\end{defn}
\begin{thm}
This is the first theorem
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

When I get the output, the body of definitions, theorems is in italic letters. Can  I get these environments in normal letters?

Comment: Also related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/non-italic-text-in-theorems-definitions-examples/38264#38264

Comment: I thought I have exactly the same issue in (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37534/normalfont-in-new-theorem-like-environment)

Comment: @karathan It seems your question was also (or even for the main part) about changing the theorem *header* font.

Comment: @lockstep There was asking for the main part, but the answer you gave me it's covered me and for the header

Answer (score 7):

Without any theorem-related package (using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch the LaTeX kernel):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\itshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\itshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\begin{pro}
This is the first problem.
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```

With [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\begin{pro}
This is the first problem.
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```

With [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\begin{pro}
This is the first problem.
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```

With `amsthm` plus the [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) frontend (can also be used with `ntheorem`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[bodyfont=\normalfont]{normalbody}
\declaretheorem[style=normalbody,name=Problem]{pro}
\begin{document}
\begin{pro}
This is the first problem.
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```