# Prevent new paragraph after theorem environment

Tags: amsthm, newtheorem

Using the theorem style as in the example below, a new paragraph is produced after the Remark. Can I prevent this? (and using the `amsthm` package at the same time)?

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

 \usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtheorem{rem}{Remark} 

\begin{document}


\begin{rem}
\blindtext
\end{rem}
\blindtext  % I want that the text begins aligned left, i.e. no new 
 % paragraph


\end{document}
```

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: That's a precise choice: theorem-like environments are always separated from the context by vertical space and a new paragraph is supposed to start after them. I can't see reasons for changing the behavior.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use `\noindent`.

Comment: Without amsthm ist works. However, without amsthm I lose a lot of advantages. @MahiPai: Thanks, \noindent works!  Since I need this only for one specific case the solution is appropriate.

Comment: @Carlos... my answer had \noindent but you said it doesn't work for you... Anyway... Happy TeXing!

Comment: Are you sure you want to make Latin-9 encoded documents in 2019?

Comment: @koleygr: ok, i overlooked!! So, the question is definitely answered. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @Carlos... Just keep in mind that the solution of egreg works without the need of \noindent (So it is better if you want to use multiple times this environment) and also consider about his comment on Latin-9 encoding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but this could help you

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

 \usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep} % Space above
  {0pt} % Space below
  {\itshape} % Body font
  {} % Indent amount
  {\bfseries} % Theorem head font
  {.} % Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em} % Space after theorem head
  {} % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark} 

\begin{document}


\begin{rem}
\blindtext
\end{rem}
\noindent\blindtext


\end{document}
```

PS: Used theoremstyle from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37475/120578)

Answer (score 3):

It's not difficult to do it, but you should think twice. A remark set in evidence within a `rem` environment *is* a paragraph (or more of them) on its own, so the text after it *should* be a new paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{reminner}{Remark}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{rem}
  {\reminner}
  {\endreminner\@endpetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{rem}
A remarkable text.
\end{rem}
Some text that shouldn't start a new paragraph. But why not?

\begin{rem}
Another remarkable text.
\end{rem}

Some text that will start a new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The behavior occurs because `amsthm.sty` explicitly includes `\@endpefalse` in its definition of `\@endtheorem`: it has `\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }`.  In a May 7, 1996 [post](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/8pi2RCh5540) on comp.text.tex, Mark Wooding gave a solution,

`\expandafter\let\csname @endtheorem\endcsname\endtrivlist`

and then wrote: "A more robust method would be to say

```
\makeatletter
\toks@\expandafter{\@endtheorem\@endpetrue}
\edef\@endtheorem{\the\toks@}
\makeatother
```

in case [...] someone else changes the original macro further."  This solution is working for me (in 2023).  The code should come between `\usepackage{amsthm}` and `\newtheorem{...}{...}`, as pointed out later in that thread by Tom Scavo quoting Young U. Ryu (who offered `\makeatletter\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist}\makeatother` as a solution).

Comment: A more modern approach would be to load the experimental `regexpatch` package and then replace all instances of `\@endpefalse` in `\@endtheorem` with `\@endpetrue` by using `\xpatchcmd*{\@endtheorem}{\@endpefalse}{\@endpetrue}{}{}`.  As of now, the `*` ("replace all") is not needed since there is currently only one instance of `\@endpefalse` in `\@endtheorem`.  Alternatively, one might be able to use the similar `\xpatchcmd` command of the `xpatch` package, or the `\patchcmd` command of the `etoolbox` package.